# How to create a site map/list

Tags: language-agnostic, sitemap, depth-first-search

I need to create a site map/list, but I need the link-name to show up as well.

What I mean by that is given, say, www.google.com, I need the following list to be created.

```
Google - www.google.com
Images - http://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
...
My Account - http://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
    Personal Information Edit - https://www.google.com/accounts/EditUserInfo
    ...
    My Products - https://www.google.com/accounts/EditServices
...
Privacy - http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy.html
...
```

The list needs to be bound to a domain, say us.example.com.

I have tried a depth first search using a python script, with Beautiful Soup to parse the links. This was unsuccessful.

Anybody have any ideas on how they would do it?

Comment: Can you please explain what the problems are? Because the question is a bit vague.

Comment: What was the problem with the method you tried? What in particular was wrong with the results it produced?

Comment: @Gamecat & andygeers : I've changed the question a bit. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the XML Sitemap builder
2. Enter the homepage path of your website (e.g. www.mydomain.com)
3. Enter the change frequency of your website (be honest ;)
4. Leave the rest as it is and click on start to let the tool make your sitemap
5. When it is done download the compressed XML Sitemap version (.gz) and copy it to your root folder
6. You can open the file with an text-editor of your choise and change the priority of documents you think. You can use and value between 0.1 and 0.9, but be aware to only give really important sites the higher value.
7. The following is very important, so that all search engine bots will know you have a sitemap. Create a new file called

[Source: [How To Create a Google Sitemap in 5 Minutes]](http://www.knowtebook.com/seo-how-to-create-a-google-sitemap-in-5-minutes-1022.htm)

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple sitemap can be a file called

```
sitemap.txt

http://website.com/index.php
http://website.com/about.php
http://website.com/blog.php
```

If you need to 'scrape' your own website for all your links you probably have setup your website in a wrong way :(

In most languages you could try either a file / direction iteration, if your using a database it should be even easier as you can just reproduce all the links at once by tweaking the way you create urls just a bit to output a sitemap.txt (or if you have more then 50 / 100 urls you might want to generate an XML)

If you need help with creating a file iterator you might want to give some more information about which language would suite you best, as a decent PHP solution might not help at all if your writing everything in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an automated web service to create the sitemap for you, you can use some of the following:

1. http://www.web-site-map.com/xml_sitemap.php
2. www.xml-sitemaps.com
3. www.sitemapdoc.com

You can find a list of services here too:
https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

Good luck!